# What is different in any day, someday, one day?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning, word-choice

I'm wondering about the differences between *any day*, *someday*, *one day*

Are they perfectly synonymous? OR they have some differences?

Comment: have you looked in a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

"Any day" has connotations that the day is expected imminently, especially when used in the idiomatic form "any day now".

"Someday" implies that the day is expected to be some distance away. (It is often even implied that the day may not actually come at all, and that the day is the subject of fervent (though perhaps misplaced) hope.)

"One day" does not come up very often in this idiom, but it would be similar to "someday".

Comment: "One day I'd like to go to America" seems quite a common usage to me. There's also _one of these days_, often used when giving a warning - "If you ride your bike as fast as that, one of these days you'll cause an accident."

Comment: What is "this idiom"? I don't see any idioms in the question or in your answer.

Comment: You are indeed correct. I don't see your point.